# Friends table for a social networking site

Tags: mysql, social-networking

I have been working on a social networking site. Here a user requests another user to be his friend (friend request). I thought of a 'Friends' table which looks like

```
Table Name: Friends
Coloumns :
    User1   - Int - FK
    User2   - Int - FK
    Request - Enum('0','1')
    Time    - DateTime

PK - (User1, User2)
```

In Request field '0' is stored when a request is made by User1 to User2 and '1' is stored when the request has been approved by User2.

The problem arises when i want to retrieve all friends of a user. I had to check whether the Request field is '0' or '1' each time. Is there another way to do so? Is it better if i have another table which stores all the details of Friend requests?

Comment: Why is this a problem?  It shouldn't be as long as your have the request field indexed.  Doing a query like `SELECT * FROM friends WHERE User1 = XX and Request = 1` should be fine.

Comment: @MikeBrant If User1 is a friend of User2 then User2 is also a friend of User1. Hence the query would become `SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (User1 = XX or User2 = XX ) and Request = 1`. Wont it be complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment you basically state that an established friendship (as opposed to a request) is always symmetric in your setup. In that case, you have basically two options: you can either store it in two rows, or select it by matching either column. The former will yield simpler queries, but the latter will ensure that the symmetry is inherent in the database structure, and will avoid storing duplicate data as well. So I'd go for the latter, i.e. some form of `WHERE (User1 = XX or User2 = XX )`. The query might well take twice as long as a query for just one column would take *on that same number of rows*, but as the number of rows is only half that of the other storage scheme, the net effect in terms of performance should be negligible.

Whether you want a separate table for requests or established friendships depends on how similar those two are, both in terms of associated data and of the control flow in your application. So for example, if you want to present a single list to a user which shows both his established friendships and his pending requests, perhaps with different colors or whatever, but in the same list, then having a single table in the database would be more appropiate. If, on the other hand, you mostly treat requests and friendships separately, then having two tables would come more natural. And if, at some time, you decide that a freindship needs attributes like `share_calendar` whereas a request needs attributes like `confirmation_key` or whatever, then you'll be better off with different tables.

If you decide to make this a single table, I'd suggest more describtive values for the enum, like calling the column `status` and the values `requested` and `established`. I, for one, would at first glance interpret a value of `request = 1` as ”this is a request only, not an established freindship”, exactly the opposite of the meaning you associate. This ambiguity can lead to errors when different people need to maintain the code. And in several years you'll be enough of a different person from who you are now that even you yourself might misinterpret your old code. So be descriptive there.

One more note: you may always use views to tweak the way your database appears to your queries. For example, you can create a view

```
CREATE VIEW SymmetricEstablishedFriends AS
SELECT User1 AS Me, User2 AS Friend, Time
FROM Friends
WHERE Status = 'established'
UNION
SELECT User2 AS Me, User1 AS Friend, Time
FROM Friends
WHERE Status = 'established'
```

This will restrict the data to established friendships only, and will take care of symmetrizing things for you. Using such views in your queries, you can avoid having to deal with all the details of the table structure in every query. And if you ever change those details, there will be less places to change.

Comment: Thanx. I guess I got my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would break your data into `requests` and `friendships`. When a `request` is approved, convert it into a `friendship`. They really are two different objects, and should be treated as such.

```
Requests ::
  requesting_user_id : int()
  requested_user_id  : int()
  date_requested     : datetime()
  status_id          : int()

Statuses ::
  (Active, Declined, Accepted, Ignored)

Friendships ::
  friendship_id      : int()
  user_id            : int()
  friend_id          : int()
```

Maybe delete the request if it's declined, or have a column for it (to keep people from repeatedly requesting the same user's friendship). You'd have to convert the request to two friendships (one in each direction) for easy indexing

```
SELECT friend_id FROM friendships WHERE user_id = ?
```

Comment: So i should store two tuples like user1, user2 and user2, user1. Is it right?

Comment: In `friendships`? Yes, that seems to make sense.

Comment: Inserting 2 rows and deleting 2 rows seems like little lengthy process.

Comment: Could be, but you'll probably do more lookups than inserts/deletes